# Format date in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've tried this

```
<%= builder.text_field (:start_date).strftime('%a'), :disabled => true, :class => 'input_date_field' %>
```

and this

```
module DatesHelper
  def formatted_to_day(start_date)
   start_date.strftime("%a")
  end
end

<%= builder.text_field formatted_to_day(:start_date), :disabled => true, :class => 'input_date_field' %>
```

all to no avail.

Comment: What is your expected outcome? We will need a little more info to help you.

Comment: Sorry. I'm trying to get the Day out of it. At the moment it's just giving me errors

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best resource I know of to help point you in the right direction. http://railscasts.com/episodes/31-formatting-time

Comment: The trouble I'm having is getting it work in a nested form - I can't work out the syntax

Comment: Nesting it shouldn't be any different than displaying it in any other form.